# Dagger - Is it possible to select a Provider based on inheritance?

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger

At the moment I have a `Base` class that contains a member I would like to inject. However, I would like the concrete type of this member to depend on the `Subclass` being instantiated. What I am aiming for is something along these lines:

```
public interface StringInterface {
    public String getString();
}

public class HelloStringConcrete implements StringInterface {
    public String getString() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

public class WorldStringConcrete implements StringInterface {
    public String getString() {
        return "World";
    }
}

public abstract class Base {
    @Inject StringInterface member;

    public Base() { 
        // Assume access to object graph
        MyObjectGraph.get().inject(this);
    }

    public void printSomething() {
        System.out.println(member.getString());
    }
}

public class SubclassHello extends Base {}
public class SubclassWorld extends Base {}

@Module(injects = {SubclassHello.class})
public class HelloModule {
    @Provides StringInterface provideStringInterface() {
        return new HelloStringConcrete();
    }
}

@Module(injects = {SubclassWorld.class})
public class WorldModule {
    @Provides StringInterface provideStringInterface() {
        return new WorldStringConcrete();
    }
}
```

So now what I would like to do is something along the lines of:

```
@Module(
    includes = {
        HelloModule.class,
        WorldModule.class
    }
)
public class BigModule {}

// Somewhere in another piece of code...
objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new BigModule());

// In yet another piece of code...

SubclassHello hello = new SubclassHello();
SubclassWorld world = new SubclassWorld();

hello.printSomething();
world.printSomething();
// Hopefully would result in :
// Hello
// World
```

This type of setup won't work though, because including two modules with the same provider will result in a duplicate provider error at compile time. It would be cool to see a solution to this problem without introducing `@Named` or `@Qualifer` annotations, or using scoped graph extensions via `graph.plus()` because these strategies necessarily introduce coupling to the subclasses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible but I think the code I've attached below is more coupled than using scoped graphs or annotations. Basically you can use constructor injection to inject concrete dependencies to your 
`SubclassHello` and `SubclassWorld`.

```
public abstract class Base {

    private final StringInterface member;

    public Base(StringInterface member) {
        this.member = member;
    }
    ...
}

@Module(injects = {SubclassWorld.class})
public class WorldModule {

    @Provides
    WorldStringConcrete provideStringInterface() {
        return new WorldStringConcrete();
    }
}

public class SubclassWorld extends Base {

    @Inject
    public SubclassWorld(WorldStringConcrete worldStringConcrete) {
        super(worldStringConcrete);
    }
}


@Module(injects = {SubclassHello.class})
public class HelloModule {

    @Provides
    HelloStringConcrete provideStringInterface() {
        return new HelloStringConcrete();
    }
}

public class SubclassHello extends Base {

    @Inject
    public SubclassHello(HelloStringConcrete helloStringConcrete) {
        super(helloStringConcrete);
    }
}

// Somewhere in another piece of code...
ObjectGraph objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new BigModule());

// In yet another piece of code...
SubclassHello hello = objectGraph.get(SubclassHello.class);
SubclassWorld world = objectGraph.get(SubclassWorld.class);
```

I don't think there are other solutions. How could Dagger find out which `StringInterface` implementations should be injected to the concrete classes?

Comment: Thanks @tomrozb, but ideally I'd like to avoid making the subclasses aware of the concrete types so that they can be completely decoupled. However, there might be an argument that says there needs to be some type coupling in the subclasses so they can keep some level of control of their contract, and your solution certainly addresses this. If no one else provides a completely decoupled solution, I will mark this one as the accepted answer.

Comment: To you comment about how Dagger would find out which StringInterface to use, I suppose this betrays my ignorance of Dagger's inner workings, but I would imagine during the compilation process it might be possible to maintain an inheritance graph based on how modules inject certain classes. As it stands, this may not be possible, but perhaps if there were an annotation that marked a module as being a part of a hierarchy, this might be possible to implement.